# Mapping the same model to multiple tables in EF Core

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have a (very old) Oracle database with multiple (hundreds) of tables with names that follow this pattern:

```
FOO_{code}
```

where `code` is two letters followed by two numbers.

I want to map all of these tables to the same entity (they all have the same columns). These tables can be created at runtime so I need to map them using a pattern of some sort. Is this possible with EF Core (6)? I believe I had found a post a few months ago but I can't find it again.

We are not using scaffolding.

[image: Diagram depicting the relationships between tables]

Comment: With third party extension, you can do that. What do you plan to do with these tables? Querying?

Comment: Yes, mainly querying because the rest will be done through stored procedures

Comment: Each table has the same columns? How do you see the query?

Comment: What do you mean, "How do you see the query?".
As I mentioned in the question, all the tables have the same columns

Comment: @BernardBorg what's the relation between those tables? Multitenancy, inheritance, hand-written partitioning? How do you decide which one to use, at what point? Do you have to combine data from different codes in the same transaction?  EF, like all ORMs, tries to give the impression of working with *objects*, not tables. Mapping is set when a session/DbContext starts and the applications don't know about it unless something goes wrong

Comment: One possibility would be to pass the code as a parameter to the DbContext constructor and use it to map to specific tables in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: If you use dependency injection *and* only one "code" is used in a specific unit of work, you could inject the code as a scoped service/setting to the context. In [Multi-tenant Apps With EF Core and ASP.​NET Core](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/06/22/multi-tenant-apps-with-ef-core-and-asp-net-core/) a custom middleware is used to pull the tenant ID from a request and make it available to the DbContext constructor through a scoped `TenantService`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, everything that you have mentioned is a pain and It will not work in case when you need to create query which uses several tables of the same entity in single query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv leaking mapping into the query is no different and and equal if not worse pain. Your answer is doing exactly the same only later in the code. You'd have to get that code to the query somehow. You'd also have to modify *all* queries to use the code, not just the mapping

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `which uses several tables` that's why I asked *why* and *how* the tables are used. There are several options, with pros, cons and restrictions. If this was a partitioning attempt, why not use Oracle's partitioning? Or a view to combine the tables? We *assume* the database can't be modified. Is there a way that *doesn't* leak table names all the way to the query?

Comment: These tables are like "snapshots". Only 1 is used per query, but I need a way to dynamically choose which one when creating the query dynamically (using a parameter from the API request containing the code itself). To complicate things further, there are multiple tables which have the same code. These need to be usable together in the same query.

Comment: I added a diagram for the table structure in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) extension. It replaces EF Core LINQ translator and allows such queries (only when `linq2db` methods are used in query). Disclaimer, I'm one of the creators.

You can define single entity for such tables, for example:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

Using extension, you can change table name on the fly. For example:

```cs
var current = "001";
var other   = "002";

var query = 
    from f in context.Foo.ToLinqToDBTable().TableName("FOO_" + current)
    join b in context.Set<Foo>().ToLinqToDBTable().TableName("FOO_" + other) on f.Id equals b.Id
    select new { f, b };
```

As a bonus you will get access for bulk operations, temporary tables, CTE, etc.

Note that it can be collision with EF Core async methods, so you can use `ToListAsyncLinqToDB()` instead of `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Can you use this alongside EF Core or as a replacement?

Comment: Alongside, it do not replace EF Core's translator if you don't ask (use linq2db methods in query).

Comment: Could this be used in conjunction with (for example), DevExpress.AspNet.Data to provide dynamic filtering and sorting?

Comment: Yes, should work. LINQ methods are the same. Think of this as an EF Core on steroids.