# Entity Framework Core use existing Entity type to query another table with same columns but different name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my SQL Server 2019 database, I have many tables with exactly the same column names and data types. For various reasons, the data was split across multiple tables (and I have to live with this...)

Let's say the tables are named like so:

- Region1_Data
- Region2_Data
- ...
- Region50_Data

I used `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate the `DbContext` with only the first table (`Region1_Data`) entity type.

I am using **Entity Framework Core 7** (but could upgrade to 8). I only need to read from the DB, not write to it, so I called `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)`.

I can now generate and execute SQL queries on that single table. But I am looking for an elegant way to do so for the other tables also, without scaffolding all those tables too.

Basically, is there some way to reuse my entity type but for querying a table with a different name? For example something like this:

```
using var context = new MyDbContext();
var rowsRegion1 = context.Region1_Data.Where(...).ToList();
var rowsRegion2 = context.Region1_Data.Where(...).WithTableName("Region2_Data").ToList();
```

Or would I have to copy the `Region1_Data` entity type at runtime, map it to a different table and "register" it with my `DbContext`?

I found some similar questions, but for EF6, not EF Core. Ex:

- [Entity Framework query table with different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602231/entity-framework-query-table-with-different-name)

Comment: I have [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095157/10646316) for similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw SQL:

```cs
public IQueryable<Region> GetRegionFromTable(YourDbContext dbContext, string tableName)
{
    return dbContext.FromSqlRaw<Region>($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}");
}
```

Do ***NOT*** whatever you do, allow user input into that parameter. Instead, pick from a pre-existing list of table names. Otherwise you are allowing **dangerous** SQL injection.